# Why this URL is not mappet in my servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea

I have the following problem with a **servlet** application. This morning this worked fine and now it present an issue.

This is the **web.xml** configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">    
<web-app>

    <display-name>Enel EDI-MON</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.quartz.QuartzListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>    
        <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Monitoraggio</servlet-class>   
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/edimon.do/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Salwf</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/salwf.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/logon.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>displaytag</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/displaytag-11.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>

</web-app>
```

As you can see I have 2 **servlet**:

The **second servlet** should map path like this:

```
http://localhost:7001/salwf.do
```

It worked but now if I try to open this link I obtain the following error message:

```
Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
```

This is the code of my **Salwf** class that implement the **HttpServlet** interface:

```
public class Salwf extends HttpServlet {

    private String msg = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        StandardConfigurationFactory standardConfigurationFactory = new StandardConfigurationFactory();

        try {
            standardConfigurationFactory.init();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }

        ConfigurationFactory.setInstance(standardConfigurationFactory);
    }

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LoggerMDC.setup(req, res);
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        String service = req.getParameter("serv");

        char serviceId = Utility.getServizio(req.getParameter("serv"));

        // The collection that have to be shown in a table inside the JSP view:
        SalDettaglio[] salDettaglio = this.getSalDettaglioList();

        gotoPage(ConfigurationFactory.getPropertiesPages().getProperty("pagina_salwf"), req, res);

        //String paginaDaLanciare = lanciaServizio(serviceId, req, res);
    }

    /*
    private String lanciaServizio(char num_servizio, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC

        HttpSession session;

    }
    */

    private void gotoPage(String address, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Logger logger = (Logger) Logger.getStdLogger(Monitoraggio.class); // do not declare 'logger' as static field in order to work with MDC
        logger.debug("gotoPage() | address: " + address);

        ServletContext ctx = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }

    private SalDettaglio[] getSalDettaglioList(){

        SalDettaglio[] salDettaglioArrayResult;

        List<SalDettaglio> salDettaglioList = new ArrayList<SalDettaglio>();

        List<RM> rmList = new ArrayList<RM>();

        RM rm1 = new RM("codiceRM1", "Andrea", "01/01/1014", "acqRiserva1", "consegnaFinale1", "descrizioneRM1", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
        RM rm2 = new RM("codiceRM2", "Andrea", "01/01/1014", "acqRiserva2", "consegnaFinale2", "descrizioneRM2", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));

        rmList.add(rm1);
        rmList.add(rm2);

        RM[] rmArray =  (RM[]) rmList.toArray();

        SalDettaglio salDettaglio1 = new SalDettaglio("codice1", "stato1", "01/01/2014", "01/06/2014", "Andrea",
                "Andrea", "Andrea", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), "fornitore1",
                "rmConRiserva1", "errore1", null, rmArray);

        SalDettaglio salDettaglio2 = new SalDettaglio("codice2", "stato2", "01/01/2014", "01/06/2014", "Andrea",
                "Andrea", "Andrea", BigDecimal.valueOf(1000), "fornitore2",
                "rmConRiserva2", "errore2", null, rmArray);

        salDettaglioList.add(salDettaglio1);
        salDettaglioList.add(salDettaglio2);

        salDettaglioArrayResult = (SalDettaglio[]) salDettaglioList.toArray();

        return salDettaglioArrayResult;

    }

}
```

I also try to put a brackpoint at the beginning of the **service()** method of my servlet but seems that it can't enter into it. It's seems a servlet routing problem.

It seems to me very strange. What could be the problem? How can I try to solve this issue?

As IDE I use Intellij IDEA and I see something strange: into the **Server** box (where I see my deployed project) I see the project with the (!) icon and if I put the mouse over the project name I can read the following message: **Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details**:

[image]

This is the server stacktrace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (it.sistinf.ediweb.quartz.QuartzListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\edimon_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\edimon_domain.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\edimon_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\edimon_domain.log00034. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\edimon_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\edimon_domain.log.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[5]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:8412:ac00:b07a:ed71:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:9092:bf:900d:11b2:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[7]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:dba:3e6e:937b:247f:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 172.16.27.64:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[9]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:b01:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[11]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:95e9:b3de:1431:7f1b:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[10]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:2301:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[13]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:4506:22d2:e7de:5a0c:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[14]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 192.168.11.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 192.168.35.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[6]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:88c4:cada:9151:3919:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[4]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:ac10:1b40:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[12]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:89ff:6d12:49cf:4354:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[15]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[8]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:cd21:3fe9:54bd:a17b:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "edimon_domain" running in Development Mode> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.04 CET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode> 
<25-nov-2014 17.33.05 CET> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "AndreaNobili", maps to multiple IP addresses: 192.168.11.1, 192.168.35.1, 172.16.27.64, fe80:0:0:0:88c4:cada:9151:3919%14, fe80:0:0:0:dba:3e6e:937b:247f%13, fe80:0:0:0:4506:22d2:e7de:5a0c%3> 
Connected to server
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (it.sistinf.ediweb.quartz.QuartzListener).
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): base config dir   : C:\EDI-MON\src\config
StandardConfigurationFactory | init(): log4j config file : C:\EDI-MON\src\config\log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[TRACE,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [TRACE].
log4j: Category root set to TRACE
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} | %X{MDC_CONNECTION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_SESSION_ID} | %X{MDC_REMOTE_ADDRESS} | USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID} | PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA} | %-5p | %c | %t | %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [2000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-APP" options.
log4j: Setting category factory to [it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerFactory].
log4j: Parsing for [org.displaytag] with value=[ERROR,EDIMON-APP].
log4j: Level token is [ERROR].
log4j: Category org.displaytag set to ERROR
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-APP".
log4j: Appender "EDIMON-APP" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.displaytag=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.displaytag" to false
log4j: Parsing for [soa.it.sistinf.ediweb] with value=[SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel,EDIMON-SOA].
log4j: Level token is [SOA#it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel].
log4j: toLevel:class=[it.sistinf.ediweb.logging.LoggerLevel]:pri=[SOA]
log4j: Category soa.it.sistinf.ediweb set to SOA
log4j: Parsing appender named "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} [USERID=%X{MDC_USER_ID}] [PIVA=%X{MDC_USER_PIVA}] %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "EDIMON-SOA".
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1000KB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log].
log4j: setFile called: C:\EDI-MON\log\edi-web-mon-soa.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "EDIMON-SOA" options.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.soa.it.sistinf.ediweb=[true]
log4j: Setting additivity for "soa.it.sistinf.ediweb" to true
log4j: Finished configuring.
:::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself:

the error was very stupid and it was caused by the fact that if I want to enter into the secondo servlet the URL have to be:

```
http://localhost:7001/edi-mon/salwf.do
```

Answer (score 1):

Your web.xml is Incorrect

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Monitoraggio</servlet-class>   
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.sistinf.ediweb.monitor.servlets.Salwf</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>edimon</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/edimon*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>salwf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/salwf.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When you write an XML file, it has to follow a DTD.
DTD defines name of tags, attributes and the tag sequence, the order in which tags should appear.

According to that DTD `<servlet-mapping>` cannot appear before `</servlet>`. You can download and refer from here
[Web.xml DTD](http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd)

`<servlet-mapping>` always comes after `<servlet>` . It should start after all `servlet-name` and `servlet-class` are mapped.

Correct way of writing `/edimon.do/*` is `/edimon.do` or  `/edimon*`  .
Here `*` it will match any text after `edimon` e.g :- `/edimonXYZ`,`/edimon.com`